# Error getting when adding reference of service class in console(.exe)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

Getting error

> A reference to "file path\file.sln"could not be added. please make
>   sure that the file is accessible and that its is a valid assembly or
>   COM component

Comment: When do you get this error? This question is unlikely to be answered as you're not giving any information of what you try to achieve and how you try it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean adding a reference inside a project?

If is this, you can´t add a reference to a whole .sln, you will need to choose, for example, a valid .dll of the service you are trying to reference.

Comment: yes i have tried to refer service.dll which is my service file but again i getting  I seem to be running into an issue when I comes to utlizing my WCF from a service host (exe). I can add a reference to the WCF (dll) to my service host (exe) and create the necessary componets to the exe; such as the service installer, service host, and the app.config, compile and then finally install the exe using InstallUtil. But, when I tried to start the service in the Microsoft Management Console, the service immediately stops after being started.

Comment: Try to test your service in your local machine with the WcfTestClient. Maybe you are having some issue with your service. The test client is in this route: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE test it and check if you have some issue or if it´s running good

Answer (score 0):

> A reference to "file path\file.**sln**" could not be added.

That's a *solution* file.

> [...] and that its is a valid assembly or COM component

A solution file is not an assembly or a COM component, hence the error.  You need to add a reference to an actual assembly.  If it's a project in your current solution, add a Project Reference.  If it's not in your solution (and for whatever reason can't be added, though I highly recommend adding it if at all possible) then you'll need to add a reference to the *compiled .dll* of the referenced project.

You can't add references to solution files, project files, anything like that.  Those are just XML metadata about projects.  You need the compiled output, the assembly.